# Ruby -s returns No such file or directory (switches)

Tags: ruby, command-line

I have this at the top of my file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -s
```

It works without the `-s` and runs correctly however I want easy switches so I want `-s` to work. When I run it with `-s` I get:

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby -s: No such file or directory
```

Is this a syntax error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only pass a single option to the command named in in the *shebang* line. Or truly spoken, if you pass multiple arguments, they will not get exploded but passed as single argument. In this case like:

```
/usr/bin/env 'ruby -s'
```

But the file `'ruby -s'` does not exist. That's why the error message.

Following the Ruby's man page, you are supposed do use the following shebang:

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby -s
# :prints "true" if invoked with `-xyz' switch.
print "true\n" if $xyz
```

You need to call ruby directly instead of using `/usr/bin/env`. This is a drawback, but doing so, you can call the script like this:

```
./script.rb -xyz
```

Comment: so is there no way to get the switch option in?